# Charge straight _____ me ( towards , to , on etc )

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

What is the preposition to be used to correct the bold part of the sentence ?

The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and **charged straight after me.**

I googled for the word charge and found different preposition  used with it like *charged straight into enemies*, so I am not able to decide which preposition to use here.

Answer (score 2):

There's not one right answer.  Different prepositions can be used for different meanings.  "Towards" is probably the most neutral choice here, as it carries the least extra connotations.

> The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and charged
>   straight **after** me.

"After" implies that you are actively moving away from the bird and it's trying to catch you.  The image this conjures is that you are running from the bird and being chased.

> The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and charged
>   straight **at** me.

"At" implies the bird ran in your direction and you were its target.

> The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and charged
>   straight **towards** me.

"Towards" implies that the bird ran in your direction, whether or not you were its target (maybe it was charging at something close to you instead)

> The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and charged
>   straight **into** me.

When "into" is used with a single person, it carries the meaning that the bird actually collided with you, rather than merely approached you.  (With a group, "into" would mean that the bird made it inside / among the group of people).

> The infuriated bird suddenly doubled back on its course and charged
>   straight **to** / **up to** me.

This doesn't work very well with "charged", but it implies the bird ran towards you and then stopped next to you.  It would be more common in a sentence like "My dog ran up to me and begged for playtime".